# RegEx - Match Word Before Single Char, But Not Double Char?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

> Iceland :Country\nEurope::Continent\nReykjavik:City

with the above string, i would like to match words that appear before a single colon, but not those before a double-colon.  additionally, if there is whitespace before a single colon, i would like it to be ignored and match the word before the whitespace.

so from the above string i would like to match "Iceland"(without the trailing space) and "Reykjavik".

i thought that creating capture groups would work, but it doesn't:

```
/(\w+(?=:))(?!=::)/gm
```

i don't know how to ignore white space before a single colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have the syntax wrong for the negative look-ahead assertion...  It's (?!pattern), not (?!=pattern).

So try:

```
/(\w+(?=:))(?!::)/gm
```

[edit - missed the other part of the question]

To ignore the whitespace, just match it but do not capture it.

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /(\w+)\s*(?=:)(?!::)/gm'
hello  ::there   :dude
```

...prints "there".

Comment: That doesn't support spaces before the colon

Comment: i'm quite new to RegEx so thanks for correcting my syntax and for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w+)\s*:(?!:)
```

Look like it might be a win for you

Comment: This will include the `\s*:` in the match. Not a big problem, since he can just use the capture group, but it changes the semantics of the pattern somewhat.